# PostSharp Disposable Attribute

Tags: c#, .net, postsharp

Has anyone used the PostSharp Disposable attribute?

There is an example in the documentation http://doc.postsharp.net/disposable#customize. The last section shows a way to customize the dispose logic (code from the example below), but it doesn't compile (assuming that Formatter is System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatter). Calling base.Dispose results in a compiler error *'object' does not contain a definition for 'Dispose'*. Am I reading this example wrong? What is the way to customize the dispose method?

```
[Disposable]
public class MessageFormatter : Formatter
{

  [Child]
  MessageSink sink;

  public bool IsDisposed { get; private set; }

  protected virtual void Dispose( bool disposing )
  {
    base.Dispose( disposing );

    this.IsDisposed = true;
  }
}
```

For classes where the dispose logic isn't customized (more code from the example below), the Dispose method isn't available to call (HomeMadeLogger.Dispose doesn't exist).

```
[Disposable]
public class HomeMadeLogger
{
    [Child]
    public AdvisableCollection<Context> LoggingContexts { get; set; }
}
```

I found this article which briefly discusses the Disposable attribute: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/774482/PostSharpin-Part. It notes that

> ... to use your parent type in a using statement you must initialize it
>   outside the scope of the using to avoid the build-time error type used
>   in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to
>   System.IDisposable

```
var order = new Order { Id = 1, OrderDate = DateTime.Now };
using (order as IDisposable)
{
   ...
}
```

This method of using works fine. Is there a way to explicitly Dispose?

Comment: Sure, make your Dispose() method *public*.

Comment: That would be fine for customized logic, but the example of customized logic won't compile. Non-customized logic doesn't have a Dispose method in your class, it's handled by the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation page is incorrect (I filed an internal bug for that). You should not call base.Dispose if you declare a virtual method, only if you override the same virtual method in the base class.

To call the public Dispose method, use `((IDisposable)order).Dispose()` or `Post.Cast<Order,IDisposable>(order).Dispose()`. The second construct looks weird but it is validated at build-time.

Comment: Thank you for your response!